# ASCII diagram formatting messed up in Nroff

Tags: ascii, rfc, ascii-art, groff, troff

I am using Nroffeditor to develop a rfc like document and adding a ascii diagram, which I handcrafted. There is a online tool asciiflow.com, which can also be used.

When I paste the ASCII diagram in the NroffEditor, it shows a messed up diagram in the generated .txt file on the right. I am not sure if it does not recognize the new line character properly, but I get the output as shown below.

This is what I paste in .nroff file.

[image]

This is what I get in the generated .txt file.

[image]

Can someone pls help why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I figured the solution, and we need to enclose the ASCII diagram within following two control sequences.

```
.nf

< Paste your ASCII diagram >

.fi
```

Comment: You probably want a mono-spaced font, also.